# Regex replacing path up to last name if it has an extension

Tags: regex, webpack

Basically I want to replace:

`/uranus/api/links/SU5HKVFl6G` to `/`

`/uranus/api/links/SU5HKVFl6G/index.js` to `/index.js`

Note here the `SU5HKVFl6G` part is random...

FYI, I am trying to do this in webpack:

```
  devServer: {
    contentBase: paths.appPublic,
    contentBasePublicPath: paths.root,
    watchContentBase: true,
    publicPath: paths.root,
    proxy: {
      '/uranus/api': 'http://localhost:3089',
      '/uranus/api/links': {
        target: 'http://localhost:3335',
        pathRewrite: {'^.+' : ''}
      }
    }
  }
```

The above was my original config but it would proxy `/uranus/api/links/SU5HKVFl6G/index.js` to `/` as well...

Comment: Try `pathRewrite: {'^.*(/[^/]*\.\w+)$', '$1'}`

Comment: If that does not work, try doubling backslashes `pathRewrite: {'^.*(/[^/]*\\.\\w+)$', '$1'}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct your reg-ex like: `pathRewrite: {'^.+\/' : '\/'}`
it will replace only these types `/uranus/api/links/SU5HKVFl6G/index.js` to `/index.js`

and,
`pathRewrite: {'^\/uranus\/api\/links\/[^\/]+\/?' : '\/'}`

this regex will replace both types
`/uranus/api/links/SU5HKVFl6G` to `/`
and also `/uranus/api/links/SU5HKVFl6G/index.js` to `/index.js`

assuming `/uranus/api/links/` part is constant.

**reg-ex explanation:**
`^` starting of string
`\/uranus\/api\/links\/` constant path with slashes escaped
`[^\/]+` will replace all characters except slash, which is dynamic string in your case.
`\/?` for directories `/` may not be present at last, and for files definitely `/` will be present after your dynamically named directory, so `?` says slash may be present or not, it's like 0 or 1 occurrence.

Comment: This rewrites `/uranus/api/links/SU5HKVFl6G` to `/SU5HKVFl6G` which is not desirable...

Comment: This will rewrite `/uranus/api/links/SU5HKVFl6G/index.js` to `/index.js`

Comment: if you want `/uranus/api/links/SU5HKVFl6G` to `/` then use `pathRewrite: {'^.+' : '\/'}`

Comment: Then `/uranus/api/links/SU5HKVFl6G/index.js` will be rewritten to `/` which is also undesirable.

Comment: ok, you want both these to happen then use: `pathRewrite: {'^\/uranus\/api\/links\/[^\/]+\/?' : '\/'}` , this regex will do `/uranus/api/links/SU5HKVFl6G` to `/` and also `/uranus/api/links/SU5HKVFl6G/index.js` to `/index.js`

Comment: Thank you, altho it is still not perfect, because if I visit `/uranus/api/links/SU5HKVFl6G` the path to the resources such as `/index.js` is `/uranus/api/links/index.js` which would be replaced to `/` instead of `/index.js`, which means I must visit `/uranus/api/links/SU5HKVFl6G/` instead of `/uranus/api/links/SU5HKVFl6G`...